# How can I scrape jquery code with python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I need help, I want to scrape this site. I was using `BeautifulSoup` and        `requests` but I can't get the value from the picture.

[image: Screenshot]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

my_url = 'https://partneredge.sap.com/content/partnerfinder/search.html#/'
page = requests.get(my_url)
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")

trazenje = page_soup.find_all('header.search-result__head')
print(trazenje)
```

I get empty list as result and no error!

[Link to site](http://partneredge.sap.com/content/partnerfinder/search.html#/)

Comment: Post your code, expected result and actual result or error

Comment: I posted code ty :)

Comment: Those elements do not exist on the page as downloaded. In the browser, they're added after loading by some JavaScript. You aren't running that JavaScript. If you want to scrape this site, you will need to either (1) drive a browser with something like Selenium, (2) run a JavaScript engine like PhantomJS, (3) read what the JS does and write equivalent Python, or (4) reverse-engineer what the JS does by watching outgoing request from your browser and write Python that does that.

Comment: Meanwhile, is what you're doing allowed by their ToS? If it is, there's a good chance they have an API they want you to use instead of scraping their pages; have you looked? If it's not allowed, even if you don't care about their rules, there's a good chance they'll autodetect your scraping and block you after a few requests.

Comment: Didn't check that, Ty for quick tips @abarnert :D

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @abarnert, you might need to use something like the [Selenium python bindings](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html) to get at that content:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://partneredge.sap.com/content/partnerfinder/search.html#/')

table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//article//header//a')

results = []
for tag in table:
    results.append(tag.text)
print(results)
```

This produces the following output:

```
['Accenture', 'Capgemini AB', 'Deloitte Inc.', 'IBM Corporation International Technical', 'itelligence AG', 'SEIDOR, S.A.', 'GAVDI A/S', 'Navigator Business Solutions, Inc.', 'Delaware Consulting US Inc.', 'Ernst & Young LLP']
```

I will say that if speed is a factor this option is pretty slow, but it's easy to set up.

Comment: Do i need Chrome installed for this? I get an error selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Comment: If you look on the installation page there are four browsers suggested, Chrome, Edge, Safari, or Firefox. You can use any of those, but follow the installation guide. You will need to add the chromedriver.exe's parent folder to your system PATH. Just Google how to do that based on your operating system.